# Error when using SUM: An aggregate may not appear in the set list of an UPDATE statement

Tags: sql

I am getting error when using SUM, an aggregate may not appear in the set list of an UPDATE statement I am trying to run the following:

```
BEGIN TRAN
UPDATE TEMP 
SET SALARY = RATE * HOURS,
RENT = (4000 * (HOURS / SUM(HOURS)))
```

Comment: The error is -- to me at least -- really clear.  What is unclear is wha tyou are trying to accomplish.  Please describe the logic.  Provide sample data and desires results and an appropriate database tag as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE TEMP
SET SALARY = RATE * HOURS
    ,RENT = (4000 * (HOURS / (SELECT SUM(HOURS) FROM TEMP)));
```